# Asymptotic bound on the number of words of weight $\le t$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

**Problem.** A *word* is defined to be a sequence of letters $a$ and $b$. For fixed reals $\alpha,\beta>0$, we define the *weight* of a word $w$ to be $|w|_{\alpha,\beta}:=p\alpha+q\beta$, where $p$ (resp. $q$) denotes the number of $a$ (resp. $b$) in $w$.

We denote by $$N_{\alpha,\beta}(t) = |\{w\mid |w|_{\alpha,\beta}\le t\}|$$

the number of words with weight not exceeding $t$. Prove that

**i)** For reals $s,t>0$ $$N_{\alpha,\beta}(s+t)\le N_{\alpha,\beta}(s)N_{\alpha,\beta}(t+m)$$ where $m=\max(\alpha,\beta)$. Deduce that $\frac{1}{t}\log N_{\alpha,\beta}(t)$ converges to some $\delta>0$ as $t\to\infty$.

**ii)** Let $z$ be a complex number. Define
$$S(z):=\sum_{w}e^{-z|w|_{\alpha,\beta}}$$
Prove that $S(z)$ converges absolutely for $\operatorname{Re}(z)>\delta$ and diverges for $\operatorname{Re}(z)<\delta$.

---

I am stuck on both parts. I would appreciate hints towards the right direction instead of a full solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Here are some hints:*

**i)** Write $\mathcal{N}(t) = \{ w : |w|_{\alpha,\beta} \leq t\}$ so that $N(t) = |\mathcal{N}(t)|$.

For each word $w \in \mathcal{N}(s+t)$, let $w_1$ be the longest prefix of $w$ satisfying $w_1 \in \mathcal{N}(s)$, and then let $w_2$ be the remaining suffix so that $w = w_1w_2$. Show that this gives rise to an injective map

$$ \mathcal{N}(s+t) \ni w \quad\mapsto\quad (w_1, w_2) \in \mathcal{N}(s) \times \mathcal{N}(t+m) $$

and hence conclude the desired inequality. Then adapt the proof of [Fekete's Subadditive Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity#Properties) to conclude.

**ii)** Write $\sigma = \operatorname{Re}(z)$ for simplicity, and rearrange the absolute summation for $S(z)$:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{w} \left| e^{-z|w|_{\alpha,\beta}} \right|
&= \sum_{w} e^{-\sigma|w|_{\alpha,\beta}} \\
&= \sum_{w} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t}\mathbf{1}[t \geq \sigma |w|_{\alpha,\beta}] \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} \sum_{w}  \mathbf{1}[t/\sigma \geq |w|_{\alpha,\beta}] \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} N(t/\sigma) \, \mathrm{d}t
.\end{align*}

Now use part i) to show that $N(t/\sigma) = e^{(\delta/\sigma)t + o(t)}$. Then deduce that the last integral (1) converges for $\sigma > \delta$ and (2) diverges for $\sigma < \delta$.

(You might be wondering why we are not testing "conditional convergence". The reason is that the notion of conditional convergence for summation like $\sum_{w\in \mathcal{W}}$ is only meaningful when we fix a choice of well-ordering on the set $\mathcal{W}$, whereas there is no canonical choice of well-ordering on the family of all words over the alphabet $\{a, b\}$.)

Comment: Really nice solution. But I am unable to prove that $\delta>0$. Obviously $\delta\ge 0$.

Comment: @TakamotoYuji, That's a good point I originally neglected. The fact $\delta>0$ can, and needs to, be verified independently. To this end, note that any word of length $\leq s/m$ is contained in the set $\mathcal{N}(s)$. This implies that $N(t)\geq 2^{\lfloor s/m\rfloor}$, which then can be used to show that $\delta\geq\frac{1}{m}\log2$.

Comment: Clever fix, indeed!